# Is it possible to keep all the DSC configurations in Version Control and make Azure Automation fetch it from there automatically?

Tags: azure, dsc

The Azure Automation DSC seems to know to integrate with GitHub, but it seems to expect only runbooks there. At least, this is what I understand from the following UI screen:
[image]

I have just started to learn DSC and have no runbooks. So far I only used DSC configurations, no runbooks.

So, is it only possible for runbooks? Does it mean that nobody works with just DSC configurations?

**P.S.**

Knowing that DSC stands for Desired State **Configuration** I find the term DSC **configurations** a bit funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, at present the Azure Automation source control integration only supports runbooks and workflow runbooks.